# Kafka uncaught exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am getting the following exception while the producer is publishing the first message, I am trying to understand what the error means

```
Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1':

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method brave/kafka/clients/TracingProducer.close(Ljava/time/Duration;)V is abstract
    at brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer.close(TracingProducer.java) ~[brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients-5.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.closeProducer(KafkaTemplate.java:382) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.lambda$buildCallback$4(KafkaTemplate.java:433) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1318) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:227) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:196) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:707) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:688) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:596) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:798) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:561) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:553) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:335) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:244) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brave 5.6.1 is too old - it doesn't have the `Producer.close()` method that takes a `Duration`. It looks like it was added in 5.6.4.

https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/commit/23172461a41bd440ff88cd20a104e621aaa33801#diff-5a863eedbf226b573522c370b4de732a

Comment: Added in version 5.6.4.

Comment: I am just stating the fact that the version you are using does not have the method that the `KafkaTemplate` calls. So, yes, you need to use a newer version; I am not familiar with brave or how the version is determined, or why you are using an incompatible version.